# BizTalk 2013 R2 supported SQL 2014 Editon

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We are planning to migrate our existing  BizTalk applications to BizTalk 2013 R2. As per the Microsoft documentation,   it says , **the recommended version of SQL should be SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2012 SP1 (Enterprise/Standard Edition). Using SQL Server Express Edition in a production environment is not recommended. The Express edition does not include certain features needed by BizTalk Server.**

We are not using any EDI or BAM. only using EAI Applications. Still we need SQL Standard or Enterprise edition? can't we use SQL Express edition in Production?.

Comment: The documentation you quoted answers the question you've asked. **Using SQL Server Express Edition in a production environment is not recommended.** That means you can use it, but you most likely will experience problems, and therefore it is **not recommended**. It's stated very clearly and concisely; I don't know what benefit you think you'll gain from having us repeat it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's very simple, NO, you cannot use SQL Server Express in Production.**

There is no way around this *and you should not be using it for DEV/TEST either*.

Actually, this documentation is flat out wrong.  SQL Server Express does not include the SQL Agent which performs many critical BizTalk functions.